# Can't get passed data in viewDidLoad method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to pass some data to my view controller class like this:

```
MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
vc.myProperty = dataToBePassed;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

I need to make some view configuring in viewDidLoad, but it seems that viewDidload called earlier than property assignment.

Then in MyViewController implementation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.myProperty); // Here i get myProperty = nil
}

- (void)viewWillAppear
{
    [super viewWillAppear];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.myProperty); // Here i get myProperty = dataToBePassed but it's to late
}
```

How can i get passed data in viewDidLoad method without implementing singleton or delegate patterns?

Comment: Are you doing something in `init` that causes the view to be loaded?  You can just add a parameter to the initializer and pass it in.

Comment: No, I'm not overriding init method in MyViewController. Is it possible to create custom initializer method for VC? I thought that all initialization stuff for VC must be in `viewDidLoad` method instead. Am i wrong?

Comment: If you're using storyboards then you can't write a custom initializer but if you are just calling the initializer manually like you are doing then you can use a custom one.

Comment: Is self.myProperty a weak property?

Comment: What kind of object if `myProperty`?

Comment: If you want access in viewDidLoad, you should use a custom initializer - most likely -viewDidLoad is called before the object is returned to the caller and the property is assigned.

Comment: @isaac No, it is `strong` property.
@Larme I tied to pass NSInteger and custom model object, descendant of NSObject.

Comment: @rockhard see previous comment, you should pass it in an initializer if you need it in -viewDidLoad

Comment: @isaac So, because i do everything programmatically i can simply override `init` method, and move all logic from viewDidLoad to init?

Comment: @rockhard There are distinctions between what you can do in initializers and in -viewDidLoad. A lot of the properties of a view controller (eg, it's views) aren't guaranteed until -viewDidLoad. But indeed you can override and do some work, particularly setting ivars or brief processing. In Obj-C all classes have a 'designated initializer' - you need to be sure for whatever class you're working, you either override or call the designated initializer. For a UIViewController the designated initializer is -initWithNibName:bundle:.

Comment: Finally, if you're passing a reference in an initializer, you typically want to assign directly to a property's backing ivar rather then setting the property which invokes the setter.

Comment: You are doing things correctly and it should work as is. You need to show more code to find where the problem is. The viewDidLoad call is not happening before the assignment, that's certain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the code sample you provide looks technically correct, I'm with @john-elemans in that you need to show more code.

There is something that is referencing the view which causes it to load and therefore causes `viewDidLoad` to fire prematurely.

In any case, if something (such as your property) is absolutely essential to the correct building of your view structure, I'd put in its own designated initializer, e.g.,

```
- (id)initWithPhotoDiameter:(CGFloat)diameter
{
    self = [super init...]; // some VC initializer that you should call
    if (self) {
        _photoDiameter = diameter;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Notice the use of the backing instance variable `_photoDiameter` instead of self.photoDiameter.   This is about the only place in a class where you should use the backing ivar, since `self` is still in the process of being initialized.

Comment: I've tried your solution and it works as i expected! But i'm still wonder why my code didn't work as it was. If i was using storyboards, same assignment in `performSegueWithIdentifier` method always done before viewDidLoad call. I think i'll accept your answer. Thanks to all who took part in finding solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:
                            @"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

MyViewController *vc = [storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyboardIdentifier"];
vc.myProperty = dataToBePassed;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

You have to set a storyboard identifier first in the storyboard for the view controller.

Comment: I'm not using storyboards or nibs. Everything done programmatically, maybe this causing problems. But, thank you for reply.

Comment: How about overwrite the init method?

Answer (score 0):

Technically there are two approaches that are quite common for lifecycle handling of view controllers related to an application.

**Using XIBs**
When using XIBs one of the most common if not the most common process to create and setup your view controllers is done programmatically. Following this process, when you initialise the view controller you have the option of either overriding your init method in order for your view controller to have the information prior to loading the view and easing up the process of adjusting drawn content. You can also create a method within your view controller to be called in which you pass the data to be used by the view controller.

**Using Storyboard**
If you are using storyboards I recommend that you trust segues setup through it. I have found that they make life easier and it will allow you to use certain methods to handle the transition. One of those is `prepareForSegue:sender:` Within that method I have found that it is easier to setup a view controller after it's initialized accessing the destination controller. You also might consider having all data there before `viewDidLoad` hence following the segue approach.